# PHP Gearman installation

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-5.3, gearman

i have trying to sort out gearman extension for php for nothing is going correct. I have tried to install gearman-1.1.2 as per the instructions given in the website.
[Install gearman](http://nguyentantrieu.info/blog/install-gearman-1-1-5-on-ubuntu/)

Thanks for the great article since the install went on smoothly. But after restarting apache2 and tried to enter php command gives me like this:

```
$ php
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gearman: Unable to initialize module
  Module compiled with module API=20090626
  PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
  These options need to match
    in Unknown on line 0
```

And also tried phpinfo() but it seems gearman is not enabled yet.
Atlast found gearman.so was not copied to /usr/lib/php5/20121212 but still after copying the state has not been changed yet.

Please help me out .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the version of gearman you are using is way too old. about 3 years 5 months and 16 days too old.

Comment: this version i have got form this website http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman

Comment: If you compiled from source, you are building it against super old headers, id make sure your php-devel is up to date with your php binary package.

Comment: yes ... I have solved the issue by upgrading gearman using pecl upgrade gearman as root and it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my vague question it was a silly mistake. I upgraded my gearman package by using

`pecl upgrade gearman` as root. And now it is working fine.