# Gearman 1.1.12 installation on PHP5.4 on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, gearman

I have tried several posts related to Gearman installation on Amazon Linux AMI. I followed the following steps:

```
cd /var/tmp
wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.12/+download/gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
tar xvzf gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
yum install libevent-devel gcc-c++ boost-devel libuuid-devel memcached-devel gperf
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

When I run the command gearmand, I can see that it is running.

Gearman PHP library

```
sudo yum -y install php-pear
sudo pecl install gearman
```

I got the following message

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gearman.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/gearman-1.1.2
Extension gearman enabled in php.ini
```

When I ran `php --ini`, I got

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './gearman.so' - ./gearman.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

So, I edited the php.ini file and added

```
extension='/usr/lib64/php/modules/gearman.so'
```

Now, after restarting apache, I get

```
Warning: PHP Startup: gearman: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
```

This is the same as [PHP Gearman installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064269/php-gearman-installation), however the mentioned solution did not work for me.

php -v gives

```
PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Mar 29 2013 20:29:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I am using Amazon Linux.

`gearmand -V` gives

```
gearmand 1.1.12 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand
```

pear -V gives

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.5
PHP Version: 5.3.29
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Linux ip-10-0-1-160 4.1.7-15.23.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 23:20:33 UTC 2015 x86_64
```

`pecl -V` gives

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.5
PHP Version: 5.3.29
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Linux ip-10-0-1-160 4.1.7-15.23.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 23:20:33 UTC 2015 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as with `pear`. I had installed it using yum. So, first removed that.

```
sudo yum -y remove php-pear
```

I then installed pear this way

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
/usr/local/bin/php -q php-phar
```

Now  `pear -V` shows

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 5.4.13
```

Then , just

```
pecl install gearman
```

then copy the gearman.so file in php.ini